# getting java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported while using rest template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to call an api using spring's rest template, but I get this exception even though I am certain the request is going through:

```
I/O error on POST request for \"http://example.com": mark/reset not supported; nested exception is java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
```

this is my code:

```
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public JsonNode sendRequest(String value) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        Map<String, String> body = new HashMap<>();
        body.put("param", value);

        return restTemplate.postForObject("http://example.com", new HttpEntity<>(body, headers), JsonNode.class);
    }
```

somebody please help

Comment: It's quite unlikely that this isolated code fails. Please specify the Spring version you are using, provide a complete reproducible example (incl. the imports) and provide the full stack trace.

Comment: Check in postman first before writing the code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error by disabling the zalando web problem library log. Its a temporary solution which i dont really understand.